# How to save the data of text box to an selected item in list box?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Here i had created an two dimensional array that data in the text box has to get stored in the selecteditem in the list box., its not working please help me out of this code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   public TextBox[] tb { get; private set; }
   public TextBox[] t { get; private set; }
   public TextBox[] t1 { get; private set; }
  // TextBox[][] textBoxes = { tb, t, t1 };

    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      TextBox[][] textBoxes = { tb, t, t1 };
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                 textBoxes[i][j] = new TextBox();
             }
        }
    }

    private void listBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      TextBox[][] textBoxes = { tb, t, t1 };
        int index = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
        textBox1.Text = tb[index][0].Text;
        textBox2.Text = tb[index][1].Text;
        textBox3.Text = tb[index][2].Text;
        textBox4.Text = tb[index][3].Text;
        textBox5.Text = tb[index][4].Text;
 }

   private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
        textBoxes [index][0].Text = textBox1.Text;
        textBoxes[index][1].Text = textBox2.Text;
        textBoxes[index][2].Text = textBox3.Text;
        textBoxes[index][3].Text = textBox4.Text;
        textBoxes[index][4].Text = textBox5.Text;

    }
}
```

Comment: It kinda feels like you’re trying to implement a grid. If you are I would recommend you use a data grid view bound to a data table. Your user can click the row in the grid and type into its boxes, the data they type goes into the relevant column of the data table

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
int pos = listBox1.Items.IndexOf(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
if (pos != -1) listBox1.Items[pos] = textBox1.Text;
```